# How to merge two objects into one in node-red?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, datatable, node-red

```
msg.payload : Object
object
```

```
HAMK307: object
a_temperature: 23.1
a_humidity: 46
a_brightness: 3703.05
a_lights: "on"
a_presence: "empty"
r_temperature: 35.59
r_humidity: 30.46
r_pressure: 994.43
a_time: object
ID: "HAMK-307"
message: "Group_A1"
```

```
timedate: object
timedate: "08/10/2022 14:05:43"
```

```
HAMK313: object
a_temperature: 18.6
a_humidity: 59.5
a_brightness: 529.4000000000011
a_lights: "on"
a_presence: "present"
message: "Time is 14:05"
r_temperature: 34.42
r_humidity: 31.59
r_pressure: 991.98
ID: "HAMK-313"
```

```
HAMK302: object
r_temperature: 20
r_humidity: 80
r_pressure: 1000
a_temperature: 25.6
a_humidity: 39
a_brightness: 2252
a_lights: "off"
a_presence: "empty"
ID: "HAMK-302"
```

Hello, I'm new to node-red and Javascript, so please be descriptive. I'm getting these 4 objects in one msg.payload and i want to merge the timedate object in the other 3 objects; HAMK307, HAMK313 and HAMK302, like below.

```
HAMK307: object
a_temperature: 23.1
a_humidity: 46
a_brightness: 3703.05
a_lights: "on"
a_presence: "empty"
r_temperature: 35.59
r_humidity: 30.46
r_pressure: 994.43
a_time: object
ID: "HAMK-307"
message: "Group_A1"
timedate: "08/10/2022 14:05:43"
```

```
HAMK313: object
a_temperature: 18.6
a_humidity: 59.5
a_brightness: 529.4000000000011
a_lights: "on"
a_presence: "present"
message: "Time is 14:05"
r_temperature: 34.42
r_humidity: 31.59
r_pressure: 991.98
ID: "HAMK-313"
timedate: "08/10/2022 14:05:43"
```

```
HAMK302: object
r_temperature: 20
r_humidity: 80
r_pressure: 1000
a_temperature: 25.6
a_humidity: 39
a_brightness: 2252
a_lights: "off"
a_presence: "empty"
ID: "HAMK-302"
timedate: "08/10/2022 14:05:43"
```

I'm moving these three objects into a table at my dashboard, currently I can pick up all the variables and they will show at the table, but the timestamp is making its own row whilst the other objects are showing correctly, except without timestamp

[image].

Comment: You are going to need to look at either the join node (which I'm 90% sure will not do what you actually want) or look at using the context allow you to keep state between handling messages.

Comment: The join node worked, but it keeps sending two messages through the join node, since it's getting the trigger from the timestamp and the value object at the same time. Is there any quick fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPREAD Operator for destructuring/restructing of objects.
Like in the example given below:-

```
var item = {
    id: 1234,
    name: "sony wf1000xm3",
    category: 'earphones',
  };
  
  var itemInfo = {
    price : 400,
    out_of_stock : true
  }

  var mergedObj = {...item,...itemInfo};
  console.log(mergedObj);
```

Comment: This will not work in a Node-RED environment because each message is handled independently, they are not in scope at the same time.